# Starting the graph lines at the same place

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to get the green line in the following Matlab code to start from the same point as the other two ones WITHOUT shifting the whole figure to the left, i.e the starting point shouldn't
be attached to the y axis. But I cannot figure out how to. If anyone could help explain how to do it, I'd greatly appreciate the help. :)

```
all_local           = [    1.0001        1.0001       1.0001   1.0001];
mix_diff_paragraphs = [    0.59     0.93    0.97   1.0001];
mix_same_paragraphs = [    0.35     0.55    0.80   1.0001];
axis manual
axis([1,4,0,2]);
y=[1 2 3 4];

h = plot(y+1,all_local,'-om',...
         y+1,mix_diff_paragraphs,'-xb',...
         y,mix_same_paragraphs,'-+g','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',8);

set(gca,'xtick', [1 2 3 4 5]);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{0,300,500,1000,1500});
set(gca,'ytick', 0:0.2:1.2);
set(gca,'yticklabel', {'0', '0.2', '0.4', '0.6', '0.8','1',''});
legend('Location','BEST','Local users only','Local/Remote users alternate on Pargs.','Local/Remote users modify the same Parg.')

ylabel('Responsiveness');
xlabel('Thinking Period(msec)')
grid on;
```

Comment: When you plot `all_local` and `mix_diff_paragraphs`, the code adds one to the `y` vector but not for the plotting of `mix_same_paragraphs`.  Is this intentional?  Because that is why the green line starts at x=0 (or the y-axis).  Note that the naming of the `y` vector is a little confusing since it is used as the x input to `plot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite a messy way to do what you did (I don't see why you'd want to change the tick labels without changing the actual x values), but this aside, just add (+1) to the green line:

```
h = plot(...
         ...
         y+1 ...,'LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',8);
```

and in the end add: `xlim([1,5]);`

If I understood correctly what you were trying to do...

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you very much for your help. :) I admit the code isn't the cleanest though...